# Vincular storyboard con viewcontroller sin usar el drag and drop

Tags: xcode, swift3

Existe alguna forma de vincular un elemento del storyboard con una variable mediante código, sin necesidad de hacer uso del drag and drop desde el storyboard al controller?

Comment: Es esto posible ?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear el outlet mediante código, por ejemplo:
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

Luego entonces tienes que ir al storyboard y conectarlos. La forma mas rapida es ir a la vista donde lo tienes que crear. En el view controller vas la Inspector de Conexiones y te va a aparecer la referencia a myButton sin conectar y lo conectas al botón que tengas diseñado, porque el sistema no es adivino.
De esta forma no tienes  que utilizar el Asistente de Edición que te divide las dos pantallas ni utlizar el drag and drop y es mucho más rápido cuanto tienes varias propiedades.